# Create Nuxt 3 UModal (Nuxt UI) dynamically

Tags: nuxt.js, modal-dialog

I have a table with multiple rows, like the following sample:

[image]

Now I want to show modal to re-confirm the action before actually deleting.

Currently I use a global variable to pass `deleteModalId` data inside `<script setup></script>`, like this:

```
let deleteModalId = null
```

Also I have implemented an function to show this modal:

```
function enableDeleteModal(id) {
  deleteModalId = id
  isDeleteOpen.value = true
}
```

Then I bind with table rows, inside `<template></template>`:

```
  <tbody>            
    <tr             
      v-for="item in list"                             
      :key="item.id"                                   
    >                                                  
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>                           
      <td>{{ item.username }}</td>                     
      <td>{{ item.fullname }}</td>                     
      <td>                                             
        <button @click="enableDeleteModal(item.id)">   
          Delete
        </button>                                                                                                 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

The modal HTML structure is also inside `<template></template>`:

```
<UModal v-model="isDeleteOpen">
  <form @submit.prevent="del(deleteModalId); refresh(); isDeleteOpen = false;">
    <div class="flex justify-between m-5">
      <button
        class="bg-grey outline p-2 rounded"
        @click.prevent="isDeleteOpen = false;"
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
      <input
        class="bg-green outline p-2 rounded"
        name="submit"
        type="submit"
        value="Confirm"
      >
    </div>
  </form>
</UModal>
```

It works but it smells not good.  Is there any "better" way to implement this, like creating the modal dynamically or at least avoiding from global variables?

Comment: You may deconstruct the `<tr>` as a new component for better readability, using a confirm dialog for each `<td>` instead of sharing the same confirm dialog between different `<td>`